# Datepicker Eternicode - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want add datepicker to my site - I created my own configuration via Sandbox:

```
<div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>

$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
startDate: "01/09/2016",
endDate: "31/12/2016",
language: "pl",
daysOfWeekDisabled: "1,2,3,4,5",
daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true,
toggleActive: true,
defaultViewDate: { year: 1977, month: 04, day: 25 }});
```

At eternicode everything is fine, but I can't find why it's doesn't work on my site:
[Link](http://pastebin.com/Y3yPagXX)

Differences:
[image: differences]

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep your all JS code inside $(document).ready(function(){......}).
2. Please change your selector for date-picker initialization as below.

   ```
   $('.sandbox-container input').datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
   startDate: "01/09/2016",
   endDate: "31/12/2016",
   language: "pl",
   daysOfWeekDisabled: "1,2,3,4,5",
   daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
   autoclose: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   toggleActive: true,
   defaultViewDate: { year: 1977, month: 04, day: 25 }});
   ```

   As i can see on your site **sandbox-container** is class not id  so please     use dot(.) before it inside selector.
3. Also I see there are two Jquery files you imported in your code please remove duplicate.

Please find link https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/a9kb79eb/1/ for your reference..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately still doesn't work - same situation as before. Any other idea, what can be wrong? 
http://pastebin.com/5ApyvkUM

Comment: I have edited my answer please have a look..And also see in developer console for any occurence..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - javascript codde should be at the end of document.